# Unable to figure out the value change of the integer in the code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, int

I have this code and I am trying to understand it. This has an int value 'currentExpandIndex' ,I couldnt figure out why it is changing because I dont find proper initiation of it. The int is first given the value -1,but later in code the int value changes according to the indexpath. I coldnt find the relation between the int and the indexpath declared in the code.Kindly tell me,why

the code is:

```
  @interface AccordionTableViewController : UITableViewController {
NSArray *topItems;
NSMutableArray *subItems; // array of arrays

int currentExpandedIndex;
}

@end
```

//.m file

```
- (id)init {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    topItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self topLevelItems]];
    subItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    currentExpandedIndex = -1;
     NSLog(@"currenyt index -init is %d",currentExpandedIndex);
    for (int i = 0; i < [topItems count]; i++) {
        [subItems addObject:[self subItems]];
    }
}
return self;
 }

   #pragma mark - Data generators

  - (NSArray *)topLevelItems {
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TOP_ITEMS; i++) {
    [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i + 1]];
}

return items;
}

 - (NSArray *)subItems {
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
int numItems = arc4random() % NUM_SUBITEMS + 2;

for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SubItem %d", i + 1]];
}

return items;
}

  #pragma mark - View management

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"currenyt index -view did load is %d",currentExpandedIndex);

}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 NSLog(@"currenyt index -no of rows in section is %d",currentExpandedIndex);

return [topItems count] + ((currentExpandedIndex > -1) ? [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : 0);
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCell";
static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier = @"ChildCell";
  NSLog(@"currenyt index-cell for row at index is %d",currentExpandedIndex);

BOOL isChild =
currentExpandedIndex > -1
&& indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
&& indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

UITableViewCell *cell;

if (isChild) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
}


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (isChild) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - currentExpandedIndex - 1];
}
else {
    int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex)
    ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]
    : indexPath.row;

    cell.textLabel.text = [topItems objectAtIndex:topIndex];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
}

return cell;
}

  #pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
BOOL isChild =
currentExpandedIndex > -1
&& indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
&& indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

if (isChild) {
    NSLog(@"A child was tapped, do what you will with it");
     NSLog(@"currenyt index -did select is %d",currentExpandedIndex);
    return;
}
 NSLog(@"currenyt index -did select out is %d",currentExpandedIndex);
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
    [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    currentExpandedIndex = -1;
}
else {

    BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

    if (shouldCollapse) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

    [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];

}

- (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index {
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *currentSubItems = [subItems objectAtIndex:index];
int insertPos = index + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < [currentSubItems count]; i++) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
}
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
[indexPaths release];
}

 - (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index {
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[subItems objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
}
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[indexPaths release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you have this line:

```
    currentExpandedIndex = 
        (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? 
    indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : 
    indexPath.row;
```

This line assign `indexPath.row` or `indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]` to `currentExpandedIndex`.

Comment: This is a good example of why using the ternary operator is usually a bad idea, it is hard to quickly see what is happening. A simple if-else would quickly show the error.

Comment: I been looking at the BOOL isChild =
currentExpandedIndex > -1.....all the time. Thank you for quick response.

Comment: well technically speaking, searching for the variable in the code and look further when it's on the left side of an assignment makes it easy to identify this line... with 1 line instructions a ternary operator is not that hard to read and is shorter than a if..else , but of course that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;
```

On each didSelectRow it will change.

Answer (score 0):

First, set a breakpoint in `-init`. Depending on how you create this controller, it might not be called, in which case it will be `0`. Try `-initWithCoder:` instead if this is the case. Otherwise, I only see this set in one place: `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, where it can be set to the row or `indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]`. Depending on what else you are doing with the table, this might be a good job for sections or expandable individual rows to simplify.